# What is the "adjunct of space" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases

Can the adjunct of time be introduced in a sentence by the word to.

like in the case *The case, which opens in the High Court on Thursday, has led **to the discovery of 300 boxes of documents filling 110ft of shelving.***

Can the function of the last sentence element be adjunct of space (time because it has led WHERE? -> space reference,) even though it is not an actual physical space?

Answer (score 3):

You could say it is an **adjunct of space** / a *locative adjunct*, more specifically one that indicates *direction*: it is then used metaphorically, as *lead* is also used metaphorically—the case is not leading a person or cattle to some physical place, but it is metaphorically leading events along a causal chain towards a result, or something like that.

As an alternative, you could say it is an **adjunct of consequence/result**, or something like that, if you treat the metaphor as a starting point for analysis. Frankly I don't think it matters a great deal how you classify adjuncts, as long as you classify them as either adverbial or attributive/adjectival, i.e. determine whether they modify a verb or something else.

It could also be argued that the directional *to* phrase with the verb *lead* is a **complement to the verb** instead of an adjunct, if one considers a constituent/argument/phrase of direction indispensable for this verb. That is, you could argue that *lead* requires either an object, a direction, or both to make sense (elliptical use notwithstanding). A verb can have several different uses/frames with different meanings, each requiring different kinds of arguments/constituents. A subject is nearly always required.

> - She led him to the volcano. *(Both
>     object and direction required for the
>     sentence to make sense.)*
> - Who will lead us? *(Only an object is
>     required.)*
> - This path leads nowhere. *(Only a
>     direction is required.)*
> - The white ship leads! *(Nothing
>     required—except the subject.)*